# Ghusul after sex

Tags: sharia, sex

Asslamualaikum
I recently found out on this site that if penetration of the penis in the vagina needs ghusul to be pure again eeven if either partner did not ejaculate.  I did not know this for a long time. Do you still have to make up for it evwn if u didnt know?

Answer (score 1):

Walaykum assalam,

Yes, you will have to make up for all prayer performed without having taken ghusl. This is because the prayer is not counted. Purity of prayer place, body and clothes are all requirements of prayer. You should repent sincerely to Allah and it is hoped that the Most-Merciful will surely forgive you. Both partners would require a ghusl. Since it was done unknowingly, then you wouldn't be sinful, but upon realizing your mistake you should take the means to correct the wrong that has been done. The prayers performed will need to be repeated but not necessarily all at once. Try to estimate how many prayers have been performed in the state of impurity. You may make up a few a day or how many you feel comfortable doing. Try to set a target for yourself because having a goal will keep you on track. Instead of praying optional prayers, pray the make-up prayers because it is more rewarding.

Comment: Nice answer! :)